# String value from a JTable to BigDecimal throws Java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, string, jtable, bigdecimal, numberformatexception

I am making a graphing calculator that allows the calculation of data with errors (i.e. 5 +-0.02). I have created an object named `Numbers3` which in its attributes has a `BigDecimal` variable. When I input the data trough the console, everything works fine. The problem comes when I am trying to retreive the data from a `JTable`; I convert the object to `String`, but when it faces `BigDecimal(String)` it throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:470)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:739)
```

This is how I am getting the object from a `JTable` to a `String`. This is working because when I print the return from `.getClass()` the output is `java.lang.String`):

```
String number = (String)(table.getValueAt(i,j));
```

Have also tried several other options, such as:

```
String number=new String(String.valueOf(table.getValueAt(i,j));
```

I would really appreciate any help with this problem.

Comment: What string are you passing...do a System.out.println("" + String); to see what you are actually passing the new BigDecimal(String).

Comment: could we see a bit of the code, what is the string value when printed to the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to normalize string to fit BigDecimal requirements:

```
private static BigDecimal parse(String str) {
    String normalized = str.replaceAll("\\s", "").replace(',', '.');
    return new BigDecimal(normalized);
}
```

Above code removes all whitespace characters from input string (which are not allowed in BigDecimal constructor).

What is more - it replaces comma to decimal point if needed.